# How to check if email exists in cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

i am trying to check if email account exists in cpanel using php and xmlapi
this .

this is what i have done.

```
 '   $result = $xmlapi->api2_query($account, "Email", "editquota", array('domain' => "mydomain", 'email' => "username", 'quota' => "1024") );
     if (strpos($result, 'not') == true ) { 
          echo 'available'; 
     } 
     else{ 
       echo 'taken'; 
     } 
     $xmlapi->set_output('xml');
'
```

its always taking the else message "taken".

Comment: Not really sure what this code is trying to do with the "not" bit, but your `== true` should really be `!== false`.

Comment: The strpos function it  requires 2 parameters that is why i am using 'not'

Comment: What is the value of `$result`?

Comment: when i echo it it prints nothing

Comment: What about with `var_dump`?

Comment: it returns bool(false)

Comment: And is false correct? Does false mean that the email doesn't exist?

Comment: false means the mail addres is available , but if i change the values of the user name provide the correct values its still remain false

Comment: i think it could be the code i am usign ??

Answer (score 1):

i h have found a solution for this

```
 '<?php 
   include("xmlapi.php"); 

    $ip = "10.1.4.1"; 
    $auth_user = 'dave'; 
    $auth_pass = 'secret!'; 
    $cpuser = 'dave'; 

    $xmlapi = new xmlapi($ip); 
    $xmlapi->password_auth($auth_user, $auth_pass); 
    $xmlapi->set_output = 'json'; //using JSON ensures a list reference is   returned, even if one result is found 
   $xmlapi->set_port(2083); 

   // for debugging result 
  //$xmlapi->set_debug(1); 

 // set to null for a full list, otherwise specify a known domain for     $cpuser 
 //$domain_to_hunt_for =  null; 
 $domain_to_hunt_for = 'extradave.com'; 

if ($domain_to_hunt_for) { 
  $args = array( 
    'regex' => '@' . $domain_to_hunt_for , 
  ); 
 } else { 
      $args = array(); 
 } 


 $result = $xmlapi->api2_query($cpuser, 'Email', 'listpops', $args); 

if( $domain_to_hunt_for ){ 
   echo "This is a refined list of emails for the {$domain_to_hunt_for} domain\n"; 

foreach ($result->data as $email_reference) { 
    $email_address = str_replace( '@' . $domain_to_hunt_for, '',     $email_reference->email); 
    $email_names[] = $email_address; 
    echo "\t'{$email_address}'\n"; 
} 
 }else{ 
echo "This is all the emails addressed related to the {$cpuser} account\n"; 

foreach ($result->data as $email_reference) { 
    echo "\t'{$email_reference->email}'\n"; 
} 
} 
 ?>'
```